# Is the following function locally integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

I wanted to know whether the function $f(x) = e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$ is locally integrable (and why) over $\mathbb{R}$. Thank you.

Comment: I am not a mathematician and cannot provide an elaborate answer, but this integral  diverges in a neighbourhood of $x=0$, because the integrand, $\textit{i.e.}$ is even with respect to $x$, and its principle value, hence, does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$f\;:\; x\mapsto e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$ is even and continuous at $(0,+\infty)$, so it is locally integrable at $(0,+\infty)$.

for $X>1$

$$F(X)=\int_1^X f(x)dx\geq\int_1^X 1dx= (X-1)$$

$$\implies \lim_{X\to+\infty}F(X)=+\infty$$

$\implies \int_1^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ diverges.

$\implies \int_0^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ diverges.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not locally integrable and hence cannot be in L1 at all (check lemma 1 and properties of locally integrable function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function) because there exists a compact subset of (-1,-1), which f integrates against test functions and goes to infinity.